# Unterlänge beim "kleinen f"

Tags: typography

Meine Tochter lernt in der 1. Klasse Volksschule (Österreich) gerade das F/f, und mir ist aufgefallen, dass sie den Kleinbuchstaben mit Unterlänge (wie bei `p`, `g`, etc.) schreiben. Vielleicht bin ich als IT-ler einfach durch die Computer-Standard-Schriftarten verdorben, aber mir kommt das ungewohnt vor - die Unterlänge im f kenne ich nur im kursiven (Beispiel auf Windows-PCs: Telefon, *Telefon*) und natürlich in der Schreibschrift.

Hat (oder hatte?) die f-Minuskel in der deutschen Druckschrift normalerweise eine Unterlänge oder ist das eine Eigenheit der Schulschrift?

Comment: "die Unterlänge im f kenne ich nur im kursiven (Beispiel: Telefon, *Telefon*)" - du meinst vermutlich Times New Roman und ähnliche Schriftarten. Hier in der Android-SE-App sehe ich deinen Text in einer serifenlosen Schriftart, in der auch das kursive 'f' keine Unterlänge hat.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Stimmt, danke für den Hinweis. Ich habe das im Text präzisiert. Auf Windows-Systemen wird Segoe UI zur Darstellung verwendet, und dort ist das so.

Comment: @Heinzi Nur mal interessehalber: Wie schreibst Du "ß"? Mit oder ohne Unterlänge?

Comment: @Uwe: "ß" würde ich (in Druckschrift und eigentlich auch in Schreibschrift) ohne Unterlänge schreiben.

Comment: @Heinzi OK, das ist dann konsistent (im Gegensatz zu der Druckschrift von pelikan.com, die guidot unten verlinkt hat).

Answer (score 2):

Ja, in der österreichischen (vereinfachten) Ausgangsschrift, wie sie in den Schulen aktuell immer noch gelehrt wird, hat das f definitiv eine Unterlänge (vgl. Schon die Titelzeil auf nachfolgndem Bild!)

Die letzte Reform war 1995 (mit dem Ziel, einfachere Buchstabenformen um den Preis eines öfteren Absetzens zu erhalten), aber f hat definitv eine Unterlänge (genauso wie g, j, q, p und y).[image]

Comment: Nach nochmaligem Lesen: meintest Du vielleicht die Druckschrift? Das gilt mE auch dort.

Comment: Ja, ich meine die Druckschrift. Sorry, wenn das nicht klar herausgekommen ist.

Comment: Wie gesagt: ändert an meiner Antwort prinzipiell nichts, auch bei der „Druckschrift“ wird in Österreich das f mit Unterlänge geschrieben, wenn es auch vielleicht nicht so ausgeprägt ist. Vgl. etwa https://materials.lehrerweb.at/schulschriften

Answer (score 1):

Nach der [Schulschriften-Seite](https://materials.lehrerweb.at/schulschriften) ist das für Österreich so. Allgemein spricht auch wenig dagegen: die schlechte Darstellbarkeit auf 5x7-Matrix-Anzeigen wird durch die stärkeren Unterschiede gerade beim Lernen aufgewogen.

In [Deutschland](https://www.pelikan.com/pulse/Pulsar/de_DE.CMS.displayCMS.209800./pelikan-kursive-druckschrift-font-download) wird, zumindest in manchen Bundesländern, ein *f* ohne Unterlänge geschrieben. Der [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundschrift) zum Thema *Grundschrift* hat etwas wenig Substanz für ein umfassendes Bild.

Comment: "In Deutschland" ist wegen den föderalen Unterschieden in der Schulausbildung natürlich falsch. Alle Bundesländer machen das anders. Kinder lernen z.B. nur in Hamburg, Niedersachsen und NRW überhaupt eine *Grundschrift*. Eine der in Hamburg verwendbaren Grundschriften hat durchaus ein f mit Unterlänge, soweit ich weiß.  Und: Unterlänge oder nicht widerspricht eigentlich komplett dem Konzept der Grundschrift - die ja als Ausgangspunkt um eine individuellle Handschrift zu entwickeln, gedacht ist, d.h. die Kinder sollen *lesbar* schreiben lernen ohne zuviele Vorschriften zu machen.

Comment: @guidot Die Schriften auf der Schulschriften-Seite für Österreich sind ja grauslich. Welcher Amateur-Typograph läßt sich so was einfallen? Die Unterlängen viel zu groß. Die Oberlängen viel zu groß. Der Querstrich beim "f" viel zu hoch. Der Querstrich beim "t" viel zu hoch. Eine Ansammlung von Häßlichkeiten ...